# Sum values from one column when match two condition using formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

When I will search date in column A like 2017-02-15 and AAA in column c then sum values from column D in column E based on that two condition, show example in following:

[image]

Comment: Do yo need in column E to SUM() values from colum D when the two condition matchs?

Comment: Have you tried hitting F1 in Excel and typing SUMIFS?

Comment: Does the following answer solve your problem? Or still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D7;A2:A7;A2;C2:C7;C2)
```

considering `A2` is `2017-02-15` and `C2` is `AAA`

Comment: thank u all for the quick respnse.=SUMIFS() is  working for me

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If it was please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: =SUMIFS(D2:D7,A2:A7," 2017-02-15",C2:C7,"AAA") its working

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the answer is valid or nearly valid. If so, please click on the V sign on the left side of the answer to accept it as valid.